# Hangfire causing app to restart job every few mins

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, hangfire

Ok So I am using hangfire for a background job but it appears to be enquing it self every few mins on a fire and forget call.

Also how do i properly report back progress of the call as you see am just sending an ok back which is probably not correct.
[image]

My Code to run the call is simply

My Call is here in my controller in my web api the docs state you can use the fire and forget to add a background task but it appears to be doing the task every few mins? https://www.hangfire.io/

What I want is for it to fire it just once when my web api action is called.

```
public class BackgroundJobsController : ControllerBase
{
    IImportsInterface imports;
    IEmailInterface email;
    public BackgroundJobsController(IImportsInterface 
           importsInterface, IEmailInterface emailInterface)
    {
        imports = importsInterface;
        email = emailInterface;
    }

    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
    public void RunImportProcess()
    {
        /* do your stuff */

        //then schedule a job to exec the same method
        imports.RunServerSide();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("BackgroundJobTask")]
    public IActionResult BackgroundJobTask()
    {
        var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => RunImportProcess());
        email.SendSupportEmail("Background Job Complete", "Test", false,true);

        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: Is your job failing and just retrying itself? The default retry count is 10. Also hangfire has some documentation on different two techniques to report job status. A polling mechanism or using signal R to push the status to the client.

Comment: No its not failing its just automatically enquing again.

Comment: The only thing I could think is if your imports.RunServerSide() is enqueing the same job again? Everything looks right.